# Makefile should bail out if a target fails

Tags: bash, makefile, grep

I have a makefile of the following format -

```
all: target_1 target_2 target_3

target_1:
    TASK_A1 | tee ta.log
    TASK_A2 | tee -a ta.log

target_2:
    TASK_B | tee tb.log

target_3:
    TASK_C | tee tc.log
```

The TASK_A generates logging output in this format -

```
<some lines of output>
Errors: 0, Warnings: 12
<some more lines of output>
Errors: 5, Warnings: 10
```

When I do *make all*, ideally makefile should bail out if target_1 fails but it continues to target_2.

One possible solution I can think of is to grep "Errors: 0" from the log files in each target and then check the return value of grep (and exit if grep returns non-zero value). I do not find this to be very efficient solution as I need to perform the above steps for each target.

Is there some more efficient and intelligent way in which I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all, if `target_2` is dependent on `target_1`, you should explicitly specify that in your makefile:

```
target_2: target_1
```

Otherwise, if someone builds with `-j`, then `target_2` will likely run regardless of whether `target_1` succeeded.

Next, you want make to fail if one of the targets fails.   Make will terminate if the return from a recipe line is false (non-zero).  I'm assuming that `TASK_A1` and friends return false if they generate errors (otherwise the remainder of this post is moot).

Unfortunately, you have a pipe which complicates things -- namely, the return from the recipe will be the return value from `tee` rather than `TASK_A1`.  See below:

```
bash> false
bash> echo $?
1
bash> false | tee blah
bash> echo $?
0
```

In this case, `tee blah` returned true (`0`), so `$?` (the return code) is 0.   Fortunately, you can use `PIPESTATUS` to get the return code from the first part of the pipe.

```
bash> false | tee blah; [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 ]
bash> echo $?
1
bash> true | tee blah; [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 ]
bash> echo $?
0
```

So... In conclusion, you could do something like:

```
all: target_3

target_1: 
    TASK_A1 | tee ta.log; [ $${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 ]
    TASK_A2 | tee -a ta.log; [ $${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 ]

target_2: target1
    TASK_B | tee tb.log; [ $${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 ]

target_3: target2
    TASK_C | tee tc.log; [ $${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 ]
```

As soon as make hits a TASK that fails, it will fail.
Notice in this solution, if `TASK_A1` fails, then `TASK_A2` will not run.   I wasn't sure if this is what you want.   If you want both to run regardless, you could change `target1` to do:

```
target1:
   ( TASK_A1; TASK_A2 ) | tee ta.log; [ $${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works perfectly and is much better and cleaner than the way I was approaching the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing nothing more of the individual tasks, there isn't much more you can do except process the output for "Errors: 0". However, you can apply the DRY principle like this:

```
runtask = $(1) | tee -a $(2) | awk '{ print; if (/Errors: 0/) y=1; } END { if (y) { exit 0 } else { exit 1 } }'

all: target_1 target_2 target_3

target_1:
        @$(call runtask, TASK_A1, ta.log)
        @$(call runtask, TASK_A2, ta.log)

target_2:
        @$(call runtask, TASK_B, tb.log)

target_3:
        @$(call runtask, TASK_C, tc.log)
```

At least that way you don't have to go through each line if you need to modify the search pattern.

Comment: idk about the rest but in awk `{ print; if (/Errors: 0/) y=1; } END { if (y) { exit 0 } else { exit 1 } }` is equivalent to `{print} /Errors: 0/{y=1} END{exit !y}`